# Выполнение обоих веток условного оператора if за один проход

Tags: c

Каким должно быть `<условие>`, чтобы код ниже печатал ”HelloWorld”?

```
if (<условие>)
   printf("Hello");
else
    printf("World");
```

Comment: Боюсь, вы ошиблись вселенной...

Comment: можно код пропатчить и занопать переходы:) Тогда условие не принципиально.

Comment: Не используя undefined behaviour, никак.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Например, `<условие>` может быть `!printf("Hello")`.

Comment: Годный ответ. )

Comment: Тогда уж `exit(printf("Hello World"))`

---
Ну то есть 

    exit(printf("hello world") * 0), 1

http://ideone.com/vHkyIX

Comment: Толку то? Автор спросил конкретно про условие.

Comment: @smackmychi: Не, это ж надо вместо условия. Гляньте ещё раз в <http://ideone.com/vHkyIX>.

Comment: @VladD а здесь проблема у автора в формулировке. Обе ветки даже в этом случае не выполнятся (заголовок вопроса).

Comment: @smackmychi: Ну, ни одно решение не прогоняет код реально по обеим веткам.

Answer (score 1):

Пришел в голову ещё один вариант. Он, конечно, для эстетов, но все же. Никто не сказал, что это должно быть честное условие.

Условие должно быть таким (символ в символ):

```
1) printf("Hello"); if (0
```

А чтобы это было невидимым, то пишем так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define cond 1) printf("Hello"); if (0
int main(void) {
    if (cond) 
      printf("Hello");
    else
      printf("World");
    return 0;
}
```

Для тех, кто не понял, как это работает, сделайте подстановку и отформатируйте код. Будет такое:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    if (1) printf("Hello"); 
    if (0) 
      printf("Hello");
    else
      printf("World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ага, тогда уж можно и совсем в открытую написать

     if ((printf("hello "), 0))
        printf("hello ");
     else
        printf("world\n");

Comment: Теперь это тред о C-Obfuscation-contest.  =)

Comment: @avp: Уже было в верхнем ответе.

Comment: Точно. Ну, слона-то (массой 10) я и не приметил...

Answer (score 0):

[[@Bob1995](/users/24148/bob1995)](/users/24148/bob1995), с языком C я лично не знаком, но, если мыслить логично, то такого не выйдет. Вот на примере из жизни:

```
if (в магазине есть мандарины) {
  идем в гости
} else {
  идем домой
}
```

Что должно быть в магазине, что бы выполнились оба пункта?

Comment: Объявление о том, что вас выселили из дому?

Comment: @VladD, никто никого не выгонял. )

Comment: @alvoro: Ну или если вы Винни-Пух и Пятачок, то вы идёте одновременно в гости и домой (к Пятачку).

Comment: @VladD, а эти двое тут причем?!

Answer (score 0):

Так не выйдет, нужно еще одну ветку условного оператора, например:

```
 if (<условие>)
    printf("Hello");
 if (<условие>)
     printf("World");
```